# how can I efficiently identify and categorize strings in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, search

I have a pandas dataframe ( over 200K rows) each of which contains a column with a string and I am trying to select each row based on whether it contains or does not contain specific word combinations. For example, consider the following rows:

```
dF["the_string"][1] = "The blue and white dog chases many cats "
dF["the_string"][2] = "the green shoe is too big for the cat"
dF["the_string"][3] = "the yellow cat is cute"
```

I would like to search for all rows that contain a given word or set of words and do not contain a word or set of words (for example contains "cat" but does not contain "dog" and does not contain "green"), and then populates a column in the dataframe, say "category" based on the combination searched for. In this case, column["category"] [3] should = "Feline".  Another example would be the string contains "dog" and does not contain "green", would result in the column["category"] [1] = "Canine" 
Given I have have several dozen such combinations, I am looking for an efficient way to do this over the large data set.
I have tried using regex resulting in multiple lines of filtering the strings similar to below:

```
dF["the_string"].str.contains(r'\b\w+\b [Cc]ats?\b', na=False, regex=True)
```

However, given I have a lot of combinations, and a lot of rows and the fact that these combinations can change - am trying identify an efficient way to manage the list and run it on the 200K rows.

Any help / suggestions ins much appreciated.

Comment: This is the sort of operation that is almost always going to be computationally a bit expensive, and so you either need to just accept that it'll run for a while or parallelize.

Comment: @oppressionslayer thanks! I was hoping to avoid having to do long lines of code for each set of conditions...I guess there is no other choice

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dF = pd.DataFrame(["The blue and white dog chases many cats ","the green shoe is too big for the cat","the yellow cat is cute"], columns=['the_string'])
dF["category"] = dF.the_string 
dF.category = np.where(pd.Series(dF.category).str.contains('cat') & ~pd.Series(dF.category).str.contains('green') & ~pd.Series(dF.category).str.contains('dog'), "Feline", dF.category)
dF.category = np.where(pd.Series(dF.category).str.contains('dog') & ~pd.Series(dF.category).str.contains('green'), "Canine", dF.category)
```

results in:

```
                                 the_string                               category
0  The blue and white dog chases many cats                                  Canine
1     the green shoe is too big for the cat  the green shoe is too big for the cat
2                    the yellow cat is cute                                 Feline
```

and you can keep adding where clauses until you get the final result. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very late to the party but working on something similar and found this but have come up with a more generalised solution building on oppressionslayer's answer:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(['blue and white dog','green cat','yellow cat', 'green chicken','brown chicken'], columns=['the_string'])
df["category"] = None

target = ['cat','dog','chicken']
category = ['Feline','Canine','Avian']
exclude = ['green',None,['blue','green']] 

for t, c, e in zip(target,category,exclude):
    if e == None:
        df.category = np.where(df['the_string'].str.contains(t), c, df.category)
    else:
        if isinstance(e, list) == False:
            df.category = np.where(df['the_string'].str.contains(t) & ~df['the_string'].str.contains(e), c, df.category)
        if len(e) == 2:
            df.category = np.where(df['the_string'].str.contains(t) & ~df['the_string'].str.contains(e[0]) & ~df['the_string'].str.contains(e[1]), c, df.category)
```